# Issue with Parsing Command Line Arguments Containing '$' in Node.js using minimist

Tags: node.js, mongodb, minimist

I'm trying to pass a MongoDB query via command line to a Node.js script using `minimist`:

```
npm run myscript -- --query='{"$or": [{"name": "John"}, {"age": {"$gt": 25}}]}'
```

However, parts of the argument that start with `$` aren't captured correctly. Expected output:

```
{"$or": [{"name": "John"}, {"age": {"$gt": 25}}]}
```

Actual:

```
{"": [{"name": "John"}, {"age": {"": 25}}]}
```

Any known issues or workarounds with `minimist` and the `$` character?